# How to decrease perspective distortion of vertical lines in a camera?

Tags: camera, distort, fspy

I took a photo of a church and processed it with `fSpy`. It gave me some camera, but unfortunately, I can't match any Blender shapes with an image.

Apparently vertical lines on a photo remain vertical, while Blender's are evidently converging somewhere in zenith.

[image]

Why? Is it possible to make camera to distort lines less? Which parameters I can play?

Comment: My guess is that the lens you are using does not match the lens used in the original. That was clearly shot with a longer lens than the one you are using. Show images for the f-spy project.

Comment: The only parameter you can play with is camera's X rotation, the pitch. The more you come close to 90°, the more vertical the lines will be. That said, I think you can make a better work with fSpy from the beginning.

Comment: @susu is it possible to change lens length directly in Blender?

Answer (score 1):

Wide lenses tend to distort things a bit, it easier to make parallel lines point towards a **[vanishing point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_point)**. Using longer lenses will help keeping parallel lines parallel. It is evident that the lens used in the original picture is longer than the one used for the reconstruction in blender.

But changing the lens is not the problem (that is very easy in blender just select the camera and change the lens), the problem is determining what lens to use, so that reconstructed geometry, matches the photo correctly.

It is not a trivial issue, or will take you a lot of trial and error to find the correct values, as the size of objects, and distance to the camera, is only valid for a single point in space, given the perspective of a particular lens.

Because of the complexity of those many different variables, it is preferable to do find the lens value and camera placement in fSpy. That is exactly what that program is designed to do. It uses the very same idea of vanishing points to calculate the lens used, and the camera placement in 3D space.

To help you better, you show a screen capture of the fspy project and how you found the lens size there. Don't be stingy with the information

[How can I recreate geometry using a photograph?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-geometry-using-a-photograph/102750#102750)

[How to find the best place to set up the vanishing point axes in fSpy?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193514/how-to-find-the-best-place-to-set-up-the-vanishing-point-axes-in-fspy)